# Check if date is within the next three months with moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What I have always returns true:

```
const dateToCheck = '2020-02-18 11:46:04'  
const isInNext3Months = (dateToCheck) => {
    return moment().diff(dateToCheck, "days") < 30
}
```

Not sure why

Comment: Because it's negative

Comment: I imagine that your `30` should be `90`, but even then, realize that this doesn't always guarantee it's within the next three months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const afterThreeMonths = '2020-05-18 11:46:04'  
const beforeTreeMonths = '2020-02-18 11:46:04'  
const isInNext3Months = (dateToCheck) => {
    return moment().diff(dateToCheck, "days") > -90
}

console.log(isInNext3Months(afterThreeMonths)) // false
console.log(isInNext3Months(beforeTreeMonths)) // true
```

Diff returns a negative value, so you need to flip your comparison, also three months is 90 days and not 30 days as specified in your function.

And hard coding the number of days is not the correct way to go about it, because you don't know if the coming month is 30 or 31 days.

You would need to do something like this [How to get list of days for last month, last three months in MomentJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088255/how-to-get-list-of-days-for-last-month-last-three-months-in-momentjs) but to check for the coming months.

Comment: Rather than find the number of days in the last three months, couldn't you just change "days" to "months" and -90 to -3?